# SSH connection get stucked at login after a few days of server uptime

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh, openssh

when i try to connect to server via `XShell` it hangs with following message:

`Connecting to 192.168.1.10:22...
 Connection established.`

Other ssh clients just hang forever.

A reboot solves the problem for a few days.

(I do not know if it's related or not, but the only thing installed on the machine is Docker + Kubernetes with default config)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: On the server: `journalctl  _COMM=sshd`. On the client: add 1 or more `-v` options to `ssh` commands.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks, will try that and report the results.

Comment: @waltinator adding verbose method, dose not seem to post any usefull info.
It stops at `debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
`

Comment: Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1185486/edit ) your post and show us the command and entire results. We might find the information useful in determinng the problem.